# Cannot access a disposed object.\nObject name: 'AsyncCursor

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Trying to return Ok response but getting the exception:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.\nObject name: 'AsyncCursor
```

Getting this on first line in if condition

```
        var users = await _userCollection.FindAsync(user => user.Phone == loginUser.phone);

        // if user found then login 
        // else create empty doc

        if (users.ToList().Count > 0)
        {
            var user = await users.FirstAsync();
            string token = new ShirtDeck.Utils.JwtUtil(configuration).GenerateJWT(user);
            return Ok(new { user = user, token = token });
        }
```

Expected to read the first document from the list.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `ToList`, effectively you close cursor (`users`), so you should stop working with this cursor after that and proceed working with the cursor result (which you currently ignore).